# Задача на сортировку списка вручную

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, циклы, данные

Надо преобразовать исходный список в список, в котором сначала идут все слова, содержащие только буквы, а потом – слова, в которых есть буквы и цифры. Относительный порядок слов сохраняется.

Пробую уже по всякому. Извините, если в коде полный бред. Я только начинаю учиться ( помогите пожалуйста решить!

Код 1:

```
a=str(input()).split()
b='0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()
c=[]
j=0

for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] in a[j]:
        c.append(a)
        break
        j+=1
print(c)
```

Код 2:

```
a=str(input()).split()
b='0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split()
c=[]
j=0

for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] in a[j]:
        c.append(a[j])
        j+=1
    else:
        print(c)
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Answer (score 3):

Итак, как я понял у нас даётся список вида

`["abse", "a4bgs", "124gf", "ada", "ofag14", "12516"]`

Мы должны сдвинуть все слова, содержащие только буквы влево.
Первым делом разберём ваши ошибки:

```py
'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0'.split()
```

не имеет смысла, так как строка уже является массивом (почти), следовательно данное выражение эквивалентно выражению

```py
'1234567890'
```

Далее:
Строка

```py
str(input())
```

так же не имеет смысла, ведь input() и так возвращает объект с типом `str`

Да и вообще я не очень понимаю ваш алгоритм, так что предлагаю свой:

Инициализируем некоторые переменные

```py
# список слов на вход
input_list = ["abse", "a4bgs", "124gf", "ada", "ofag14", "12516"]

# Символы цифр
numbers = '1234567890'

# Массивы, в котором будут хранится слова только 

# Из букв
letters_only = []

# Из букв и цифр
letters_numbers = []
```

Теперь проходимся по каждому слову в оригинальном массиве и, если слово содержит цифры, то добавляем его в список `letters_numbers`, иначе в `letters_only`:

```py
def contains_number(word): # Содержит ли слово цифру
    for letter in word: # Для каждого символа
        if letter in numbers: # если символ находится в списке чисел
            return True
    return False

for word in input_list: # Для каждого слова из массива
    if contains_number(word): # Если содержит число
        letters_numbers.append(word) # Добавляем в список слов с числами
    else: # Иначе
        letters_only.append(word) # добавляем в список слов без чисел
```

Таким образом у нас получается 2 массива, где в `letters_only` хранятся **только** слова с буквами, а в `letters_numbers` слова с буквами и числами, при этом в обоих списках такой же порядок, что и в оригинальном. Теперь мы можем просто объединить 2 этих списка:

```py
print([*letters_only, *letters_numbers])
# ['abse', 'ada', 'a4bgs', '124gf', 'ofag14', '12516']
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @Анастасия, здесь принято благодарить за ответ немного иначе. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Фильтруем исходный список дважды - сначала оставляем только буквы [`.isalpha`](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-tekstovymi-strokami-str-python/metod-str-isalpha/), потом НЕ только буквы `not .isalpha()`, две части склеиваем.

```
lst = ['aaa','12345','x2345','bbb','1a2b3c','ccc','ddd10']
lst = list(filter(str.isalpha, lst)) + list(filter(lambda x: not x.isalpha(), lst))
print(lst)
```

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', '12345', 'x2345', '1a2b3c', 'ddd10']
```

**Если допустимо использование встроенных функций сортировки**, то так:

```
lst = sorted(lst, key=str.isalpha, reverse=True)
```

При равных ключах сортировки порядок следования элементов [сохраняется](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts)

> Сортировки гарантированно будут стабильными. Это означает, что если
> несколько записей имеют один и тот же ключ, их первоначальный порядок
> сохраняется.

Для всех чисто буквенных строк ключ сортировки == True, для остальных он == False.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: @Анастасия, здесь принято благодарить за ответ немного иначе. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](/help/someone-answers)